# cefsharp: is it possible to catch webcam start/stop events?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I need to collect statistics in my cefsharp-based program when user started and stopped streaming via webcam. is it possible?

have no idea how it should works. I expect to handle some events or something like it. please help me!

Comment: There's no specific apis for this, you'd have to see if there's a JavaScript event you can hook.